# Changing ToString value for checkedListBox

Tags: c#, tostring, checkedlistbox

Currently creating a windows form application program based on the decorator pattern in C#. The program is structured to have one main class ("Computer") of which is extended to other classes(as wrappers) which form the options available.

Problem: Using a checkedboxlist where user has the choice to choose between options which makes text specific to each option appear in one label when they are checked no matter if only one(only that checked option text will be shown after the label text) or all are checked (all checked options text will be shown one after the other after the label text). Following code shows the set text for the latest option checked in the label and it does not remove the text were the user to uncheck all options.

```
foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            Computer computer = (Computer)itemChecked;
            label1.Text = "" + computer.description();
        }
```

That problem was solved on here but the solution replaced "description" with ToString. My problem with that is, **I am looking to use what is held in "description" for the text in the label rather than what is being held in ToString which is being used to name each checked option.** Below are code examples of them both from the main class (Computer):

```
public virtual String description()
    {
        return "Currently in basket is a Computer ";
        //return this.ToString();
    }

public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Desktop";
    }
```

The reason behind that is to keep to the decorator pattern structure, ToString bypasses that as it can be used in the same way without the decorator pattern structure. The solution spoken of before follows:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Unchecked) //Continue if the new CheckState value of the item is changing to Checked
    {
        label1.Text += "a " + checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString() +", "; //Append ("a " + the item's value + ", ") to the label1 Text property
    }
        else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked && e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked) //Continue if the new CheckState value of the item is changing to Unchecked
        {
            label1.Text =  label1.Text.Replace("a " +checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString() + ", ", ""); //Replace ("a " + the item's value + ", ") with an empty string and assign this value to the label1 Text property
        }
}
```

A solution, I think found on another topic(can't remember exactly), much closer to what I am looking for, below, uses "description" for the value of the label while the ToString stays as the value for the options. However this code brings an error of there being no definition of "CheckedItem" nor any extension method by the very same name (end of the fourth line):

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                Computer computer = (Computer)checkedListBox1.CheckedItem;
                label1.Text = "" + computer.description();
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "";
            }
```

P.S. I am a novice/beginner programmer, excuse any inconsistencies or badly explained parts. Thank you.

Comment: Hey madman, It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Adding code is generally a good idea but here you have too much. Please try to rephrase your question to be more concise.

Comment: @Mataniko How is that? Hope I did not cut out too much or changed too much. Also, given that I've more or less gone back to my original problem would it be preferable to change the question/topic name to something more appropriate which at the moment I can't think of a better wording for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood what you want to do, then you need to create a public function that returns Computer.ToString():

```
public string Description(){
    return this.ToString();
}

protected override ToString(){
    /// and here goes the code you need.
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Now it's an answer but before your edit it was simply a request for clarification. Maybe I just saw it at the wrong time :)

Comment: @madman, if my answer helps you solving your trouble, then please, don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: @Victor What would your code do as I'm struggling to work out how it would work? One of the reasons as to why would include not being entirely sure where I would be placing those two, would the new description function be a new function in the main class (Computer) as well as the wrappers or just in Computer? Also, what would be the the code you are alluding to in the ToString override? I'm already using ToString to set the options in each class (example shown below).

    `public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Desktop";
        }`

Comment: First of all, you can place that two functions anywhere in your class; secondly, `Description()` will be available to almost anything "linked" to your class. Excuse me if I missunderstood your question, maybe, you. should be more concise in your question.

Comment: Right, so those two would replace my current Description and ToString functions? What it does is makes the description the same as the ToString by making the description pull what it needs from the ToString functinon, correct?

Comment: @Victor Given, I hope, the problem has been clarified in my question after my edit, is there any other way which I could code the checkedlistbox which would allow me to keep my current structure i.e.description for label content and ToString as option names?

Comment: what is the output error of your last written code? could you also post a screenshot of your application?

Comment: @Victor At the moment, I have no errors. It just does not perform how I expect/want it too. The only error I get is when I switch to the for loop instead of itemcheck for my checklistbox (last 2 snippets of code in question) I get "'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox' does not contain a definition for 'CheckedItem' and no extension method 'CheckedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".
![App Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/96377529.jpg/)